# How do I mount loop device with zfs in fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, zfs

How do I mount loop device with zfs in fstab ?

Here is how I created it:

```
fallocate -l 150G /jdata/zfs_psql.disk
sudo losetup /dev/loop2 jdata/zfs_psql.disk
sudo zpool create -f -O atime=off -O compression=lz4 -O recordsize=128K zfsdisk /dev/loop2
```

then I added following string to `fstab`

```
/jdata/zfs_psql.disk  /zfsdisk zfs loop  0 0
```

on which `mount -a` says

```
filesystem 'zfsdisk' cannot be mounted, unable to open the dataset
```

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

In your first block of code you create and then destroy the zpool.  Try it again except run the commands

```
fallocate -l 150G /jdata/zfs_psql.disk 
sudo losetup /dev/loop2 jdata/zfs_psql.disk
sudo zpool create -f -m legacy -O atime=off -O compression=lz4 -O recordsize=128K  zfsdisk /dev/loop2
```

You need to set the zpool mountpoint to legacy which used fstab.  Zfs normally will try to mount devices automatically at boot time but since you are using a file instead of a device, automounting won't work.  So the `legacy` mountpoint and the use of `fstab` is needed.

Now `fstab`

```
/jdata/zfs_psql.disk  /zfsdisk zfs loop  0 0
```

With `mount -a` should work as you expected.  However it still might give you an error on startup due to the order of mounting since you need to have the base filesystem fully mounted first before the loop file.  In that case you will need to add the noauto option with loop.

`/jdata/zfs_psql.disk  /zfsdisk zfs loop,noauto  0 0`

Comment: Isn't the string that you are suggesting should be added to fstab exactly the same as that the OP has already added to his file?

Comment: Yes it is.  The isssue isn't the fstab file.  The issue is he creates and then deletes the zfs pool.  In the original post, the OP had an extra line of code that deleted the pool.  The other issue is that you need to set the zpool mountpoint to legacy for the fstab to work.  Lastly, zfs really really really should be on an actually physical disk.  Using it in a file can cause unexpected results.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the first time you mount it, you are going to have to use the zfs mount command instead of just mount.  After you reboot, it should work as expected, but not before since you are using a file instead of a disk.